# Reordering items on screen, bringing a frame to the front

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a new frame from an image, but when the new frame opens it is behind everything else on the screen.

Is there a way to bring it to the front?

Code:

```
if ([touch view] == _imageOne)
{
    CGRect newFrame = _imageOne.frame;
    newFrame.size.width -= 280;
    newFrame.size.height -= 280;
    newFrame.origin.x += 3.2;
    newFrame.origin.y -= 100;
    _imageOne.frame = newFrame;
}
else if ([touch view] == _imageTwo)
{
    CGRect newFrame = _imageTwo.frame;
    newFrame.size.width -= 280;
    newFrame.size.height -= 280;
    newFrame.origin.x += 95;
    newFrame.origin.y -= 100;
    _imageTwo.frame = newFrame;
}
```

I have tried adding this

```
[_imageOne.superview bringSubviewToFront:_imageOne];
```

after

```
_imageOne.frame = newFrame;
```

but that makes the image just disappear for some reason..
Thanks

Comment: please share code...

Comment: Googling 'bring subview to front programmatically' gave me a ton of answers to this question

Comment: I have added a snippet of my code now, Im not quite sure how to apply the other answers to my situation

Answer (score 1):

You can bring your image to the front like this:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   if ([touch view] == _imageOne)
   {
     CGRect newFrame = _imageOne.frame;
     newFrame.size.width += 280;
     newFrame.size.height += 280;
     newFrame.origin.x -= 3.2;
     newFrame.origin.y += 100;
     _imageOne.frame = newFrame;
     [_imageOne.superview bringSubviewToFront:_imageOne];
   }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have added some of my code to the original question now. Im not sure how to apply this to my situation. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason when I now click on the image it just disappears! @peig

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you need, but in order to bring the subview to front (inside the custom UIView class):

```
UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
[self.superview bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have added some of my code to the original question now. Im not sure how to apply this to my situation. Thanks